# matrices multiplication using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code, why is there an output, mathematically it should give an error

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                      
arr = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

out:
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])

arr*arr                                                                                                                                                                  

out : array([[ 1.,  4.,  9.],
            [16., 25., 36.]])
```

Comment: That's element-wise multiplication when operating on arrays.  The operator for matrix multiplication is `@`

Answer (score 2):

The * operator multiplies values in place. It seems like you want the @ operator, which performs a dot product between the two matrices.

Example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2])
b = np.array([[3], [5]])
```

a * b returns: `[[3, 6],[5, 10]]`

a @ b returns: `13`